# Use Me. in functions

Tags: vba

First my sub looked like this:

```
Sub DeleteGraph()

For Each objCht In Me.ChartObjects
    For Each s In objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection
        s.Delete
    Next s
Next objCht

End Sub
```

This didn't work when called from the main code because of Me.

Then I tried this:

```
Sub Main()

     Dim test As Worksheet
     Set test = Me.CodeName
     DeleteGraph test
End sub

Sub DeleteGraph(sheets As Worksheet)
    For Each objCht In sheets.ChartObjects
        For Each s In objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection
            s.Delete
        Next s
    Next objCht
End Sub
```

This didn't work of the "Set test = Me.CodeName"

I searched around the web and found out that I might have to use 'CallByName' but I can't seem to make it work. Is this the right approach and if so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use `ActiveSheet`? What object is `Me` supposed to represent if it isn't the active sheet?

Comment: I guess it could work but I'm just not too happy about using 'ActiveSheet'. Is there a way to make it work without using activesheet?

Comment: You could obviously hard-code the worksheet name, but calling `ActiveSheet` once at the very start to pull it into a variable isn't bad - i.e., `Set test = ActiveSheet`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you describe your problem in more detail perhaps someone could suggest a more specific solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA `Me` is context sensitive.  It provides a reference to the parent object.  If your code is declared within `ThisWorkbook` `Me` will point to the current [workbook object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx).  If you declare your code within a userform `Me` will refer to that [userform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264663.aspx).

I suspect your code was originally declared within a [Sheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx).

[image: Worksheet objects with IDE]

From here it would access to the current [worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx), which contains the `ChartObjects` object.

One way to fix your code is to move it into the required worksheet.  You could also parameterise the workbook name, like so:

```
Sub DeleteGraph(ByVal WorksheetName AS String)

    For Each objCht In Sheets(WorksheetName).ChartObjects
        For Each s In objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection
            s.Delete
        Next s
    Next objCht

End Sub
```